# Can a blackberry HTTP request error out immediately if there's no connection available?

Tags: http, blackberry, java-me

I have an HTTP connection, opened by

```
HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
```

where `url` is one of:

- `http://foo.bar;deviceside=false`
- `http://foo.bar;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public`
- `http://foo.bar;deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=xxxxxxx`
- `http://foo.bar;deviceside=true;interface=wifi`

Is there any way to cause the request to error out immediately if the connection cannot be established because the device is not connected to a network?  As it is, it takes about a minute to timeout in many cases (specifically on the first call to get the information from the network: `c.getResponseCode()`)

Edit:  I mean error out.  In one case, Wifi, specifically, it will sit around for several minutes if the wifi is not on before timing out, and I want it to stop right away.

Comment: What does "timeout immediately" mean?  Timeout -- by definition -- takes some time.  Do you mean "get an error"?

Comment: Could you fix your question title to remove the confusing "timeout immediately" business?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the [RadioInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html) class to check if there is a connection and if the radio is turned on before trying to make a connection.  Then you can just display a message to the user or turn the radio on (if it's off) before trying to connect, makes for a much better user experience.

Try using:

```
if (RadioInfo.getState() == RadioInfo.STATE_OFF)
OR
if (RadioInfo.getSignalLevel() == RadioInfo.LEVEL_NO_COVERAGE)
```

To check connection status before connecting.

Answer (score 1):

I encase my posts in a thread to timeout faster.  Make sure your "PostThread" catches all exceptions (and saves them).

```
public byte[] post(String url, byte[] requestString){
    PostThread thread=new PostThread(url, requestString);

    synchronized(thread){
        try{
            thread.start();
            thread.wait(TIMEOUT);
        }catch(Throwable e){

        }//method
    }//synch

    if (thread.isAlive()){
        try{
            thread.interrupt();
        }catch(Throwable e){

        }//method
        D.error("Timeout");
    }//endif

    if (thread.error!=null) D.error(thread.error);
    if (thread.output!=null) return thread.output;
    throw D.error("No output");
}//method
```

There is also the `ConnectionTimeout` parameter, which I have not tested:  eg `socket://server:80/mywebservice;ConnectionTimeout=2000`

Answer (score 0):

Not any way that can be specified programmatically.  It can be irritating, but a connection from a mobile device - especially a BlackBerry - generally goes through a few different networks and gateways before reaching the destination server: wireless->Carrier APN->Internet->BES (maybe)->foo.bar server so a large timeout is built-in to account for potential delays at any of those points.

You can control default device connection timeout from your BES/MDS server (or in the JDE, from the MDS\config\rimpublic.property file) - but that probably won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a Timeout check from a different thread, Because this is gonna happen even when the connection is established, say the network latency is very high, so u dont want the user to wait for so long or such thing.

So, in that case have a check from a different thread, whether the current  time minus time entered for initiating the connection is more than your set time, close the connection using connection.close()!